# How do i strip or rename symbols from iOS frameworks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, linker-errors

I need to fix a bug in an underlying iOS framework that is linked to [route-me](https://github.com/danielgard/route-me/commit/72120430d73e0c64cd043d7e169999c789392b35) and when i include the new code I'm getting

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RMProjection in frameworks/blah.framework/blah(RMProjection.o) and
```

Is there a way to stip the symbol from the blah.framework and use my compiled code instead?
I'm aware of: `strip -s <symbol file> -u <library>` but can't get it to work

Also tried doing a find and replace

```
perl -n -p -e 's/RMProjection/XRMProjection/g' < frameworks/blah.framework/blah.bak > frameworks/blah.framework/blah
```

in the linked binary, which results in this error:

```
ld: in frameworks/blah.framework/blah, file is universal but does not contain a(n) i386 slice for architecture i386
```

Thanks